# How to chmod folder data/data/com.example.anotherapp

Tags: android, backup, directory, restore, chmod

I make an application to backup & restore app and data with roottools.

I backup folder data/data/com.example.anotherapp to sdcard. Now, I uninstall/reinstall and copy folder com.example.anotherapp to data/data/ but app can't run.

How to chmod folder com.example.anotherapp?

```
    public static boolean restoreDatabase(Context context, AppManagerItem item) {
    String from = "/data/data/";
    File fileOut = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    String to = fileOut.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
            + item.getPackageName();

    to = normalizeParameter(to);
    boolean isSuccess = false;

    String comando = "cp -r " + to + " " + from;

    Process suProcess;
    try {
        suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
                suProcess.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(comando + "\n");
        os.flush();
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        try {
            int suProcessRetval = suProcess.waitFor();
            if (255 != suProcessRetval) {
                // Acceso Root concedido
                isSuccess = true;
            } else {
                // Acceso Root denegado
                isSuccess = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.w("Error ejecutando el comando Root", ex);
        }

        String chmod = "chmod -R 757 " + from + item.getPackageName();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(chmod);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
String path = "/yourFolder";
String[] chmod = { "su", "-c","chmod 777 "+path };
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(chmod);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It's has been chmod but the app restored not working. :(